# What is the reason for the following error ?

Tags: php

**index.php**

```
<?
include "controller.php"
?>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?
include "class/clientclass.php";
?>
```

**class/clientclass.php**

```
<?
include "configuration.php";
include "class/database.php";
$db=new Database();
?>
```

**configuration.php**

```
<?php
class myConfig {
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = 'root';
    public $db = 'dojo';

} ?>
```

**class/database.php**

```
<?
    class Database extends myConfig {

        function Database()
        {

                mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
                mysql_select_db($this->db);

        }
    }
?>
```

Now the error I get is

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class myConfig in /var/www/dojo/configuration.php on line 2
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: You have declared the class myConfig somewhere before. Search your files for such a class. If you can't find it, just rename the class and it will work.

Comment: Do you use any frameworks like Yii?

Comment: Use `require_once` or `include_once`. Also it's a good practice to use `__autoload`.

Comment: No. i'm just using that 5 files

Comment: hope changing class name from `myConfig` to something else will solve the problem...

Comment: I use both include_once and rename the myConfig to config but again I get the error `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class config in /var/www/dojo/configuration.php on line 2`

Comment: Is `muConfig` real name of your class. If not it maybe already declared in some third-party library. Use namespaces to avoid situations like this.

Comment: I'm just using that 5 files only. Not using any other libraries and framework.

Comment: @vusan PHP comes with built-in classes.

Comment: Thanks for all. Actually I just try to show my problem with that 5 files but In my code there is include "class/clientclass.php" somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think changing the class name to something other than myconfig will do the trick. Some where in your code there is a class named myConfig.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
namespace Config;
class myConfig {
    public $host = 'localhost';
    public $user = 'root';
    public $password = 'root';
    public $db = 'test';

}
```

Try this.

Comment: Same error. But how that works?